# Unable to attach to the crashing process. The correct version of pdm.dll is not registered

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, javascript-debugger

In my Visual Studio 2012, all of a sudden the javascript debugger stopped working. I tried the following options and nothing worked.

a. Repair Visual Studio 2012
b. Added 'debugger' in javascript file and it throwed the follow message,

"Unable to attach to the crashing process. The correct version of pdm.dll is not registered. Repair your Visual Studio installation, or run 'regsvr32.exe "%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\VSDebug\pdm.dll"'

Please advise how to proceed further. My system configuration is,

> Windows 7 64 bit
>   IE 8
>   Visual Studio 2012 premimum.

Thanks in advance,
Vim